# How to check when webpage reload button is pressed in Java

Tags: java, servlets

I'm using JSP-s and Servlets, and I don't know how to check if a client asks for reloading the page. I need to redirect to homepage whenever a user tries to reload. Is there any method like `request.getAction();` so that I can check if it equals to "reload"? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java plays on server side and Javascript plays on client end.

```
request.getAction();
```

Is server side code and reload happens on client end.

You need some javascript to know it

```
window.onbeforeunload = funcRef
```